# Geometry file for unit square - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve a PDE on a regular mesh on the unit square. I found the regular mesh generator `poimesh`, which seems to do the job, but I cannot see how to create a geometry file for the unit square. So my question is:

> How do I create a geometry file for the unit square in Matlab?

Comment: Do you want to use the PDE toolbox for what you are doing, or you want to do something else? Just creating a mesh can be trivially done. Oterwise, [PDE toolbox](http://www.mathworks.se/help/pde/index.html#bta4e0m) documentation has tutorials on how to do things.

Comment: @angainor: Yes, I do wand to use the PDE toolbox, but I want to obtain the values of the solution on a regular grid to be able to use them in another problem. I know that PDE toolbox creates automatically all the files once you've drawn the domain, but I want to use the commands to include them in a m file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a unit square geometry, you can do the following

```
g='squareg'; % The unit square
[p,e,t]=poimesh(g, nx, ny);
```

I realize this is not so easy to find. Have a look at examples and e.g., [here](http://www.mathworks.se/help/pde/examples/poisson-s-equation-on-rectangular-domain-using-a-fast-poisson-solver.html)

Comment: Thank you. I've searched this but wasn't able to find it.